# ¿Como usar el método filter() de javascript?

Tags: javascript, método

Se que en javascript existe un método llamado filter pero no logro entender como se usa correctamente. Les agradecería mucho su ayuda gracias.

Comment: Mejor explicado que MDN no hay: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

Comment: Has leído documentación sobre el método? en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) está muy claro.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿Has leído [ask]?

Answer (score 2):

La función `filter` se utiliza para extraer elementos de una colección o arreglo.

Recibe como parámetro de entrada una función que debe retornar un valor true o false.

La función `filter` recorrerá la colección, y devolverá todos los elementos que cumplan la condición booleana.

Por ejemplo: dado un arreglo de nombre lista,

```js
var lista = [1,2,3,4,5]

//la funcion que se le pasa como parametro a filter, devuelve "true" si el elemento cumple la condición.
//en este caso, cuando el elemento es par
var resultado = lista.filter(function(elemento){
  //aquí se reemplazará elemento por c/u de los numeros del arreglo
  //y se retornarán solamente aquellos cuyo modulo sea igual a cero.
  return (elemento % 2) == 0 
})

console.log(resultado) // el resultado es un arreglo: [2,4]
```